# Is every boolean algebra isomorphic to the quotient of a powerset algebra?

Tags: ideals, boolean-algebra

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be a boolean algebra. Then we know that $\mathbb{B}$ is isomorphic to an algebra of sets, *viz.* ${h:\mathbb{B}\longrightarrow \mathrm{Clopen}(\mathrm{Ult}(\mathbb{B}))\subseteq\wp(\mathrm{Ult}(\mathbb{B}))}$ via $h(b)=U_{b}=\{\mathfrak{F}\in\mathrm{Ult}(\mathbb{B})\mid b\in\mathfrak{F}\}$.

I want to know, whether there is a powerset algebra $\wp(X)$ and an epimorphism, ${g:\wp(X)\longrightarrow\mathbb{B}}$. This is equivalent to the question: is there a powerset algebra $\wp(X)$ and an ideal $\mathcal{I}\subseteq \wp(X)$, such that $\mathbb{B}\cong\wp(X)/\mathcal{I}$.

I am also aware of the **Loomis-Sikorski Theorem**: Every $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra is isomorphic to the a quotient $\mathbf{F}/\mathcal{I}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is a $σ$-field of sets and $\mathcal{I}\subseteq\mathbf{F}$ is a $\sigma$-ideal. Is there an equivalent theorem for complete boolean algebras?

---

UPDATE: Answered by @**Keith Kearnes** here [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306578/is-every-complete-boolean-algebra-isomorphic-to-the-quotient-of-a-powerset-algeb].

Comment: Simultaneous crosspost to MathOF: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306578/is-every-boolean-algebra-isomorphic-to-the-quotient-of-a-powerset-algebra

Comment: The Cantor set is not homeomorphic to a closed subset of a Stone-Cech compactification of a discrete set (since any converging sequence therein is eventually constant). By Stone duality, this reflects in the fact that the corresponding Boolean algebra is not quotient of a power set (@მამუკაჯიბლაძე 's argument yields something more general but I wanted to point out this topological interpretation).

Comment: @YCor on which site is it better to post?

Comment: Not on both. I'd say, on MathSE, and then if no answers after a few days, on MathOF, with links in both directions (and taking into account relevant comments to the MathSE post, if applicable).

Answer (score 4):

A free algebra on an infinite set is not complete (exercise). If it would be a quotient of a powerset it would be a retract of it (exercise), and a retract of a complete algebra is complete (exercise).

Practically the same argument shows that the same algebra is also not a quotient of any countably complete one.

Another argument uses the fact that images of atoms under surjective homomorphisms are either 0 or atoms themselves.

Since there is some controversy in comments, let me try to supply an argument for that. Take $\pi:P\twoheadrightarrow B$ and suppose $a\in P$ is an atom. Take any $x\leqslant\pi(a)$. Choose $y\in P$ with $\pi(y)=x$. Then also $\pi(a\land y)=x$ (since $\pi(a\land y)=\pi(a)\land\pi(y)=\pi(a)\land x=x$).

Now since $a$ is an atom, either $a\land y=a$ or $a\land y=0$, so that either $x=\pi(a)$ or $x=0$.

**However to the contrary of what I stated, this does not imply that an atomless algebra cannot be quotient of a powerset**; thanks to JDH for noticing that.

In fact for complete algebras the answer seems to be positive. In fact there is [a theorem by Sikorski](http://rcin.org.pl/dlibra/doccontent?id=24056) that injective objects in Boolean algebras are precisely the complete ones. Thus any embedding $i:B\hookrightarrow P$ of a complete Boolean algebra $B$ as a subalgebra of any Boolean algebra $P$ admits a retraction $\pi:P\twoheadrightarrow B$ (i. e. $\pi i$ is identity). Thus in fact any complete Boolean algebra is a *retract* of a powerset.

A [proof](http://planetmath.org/SikorskisExtensionTheorem) can be found on planetmath. Note that it uses AC; that planetmath page claims that it is not known whether AC is unavoidable.

I believe also that not every quotient of a powerset is complete, i. e. retract - e. g. I think quotient by the ideal of finite subsets is not complete.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I’m concerned about just the complete boolean algebras. Are they isomorphic to quotients of powerset algebras?

Comment: @Thomas I've added this too. I believe you should modify the original question accordingly.

Comment: I have a complete Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$. So there is a Boolean-algebra-monomorphism $h:\mathbb{B}\longrightarrow\wp(X)$, where $X=\mathrm{Clopen}(X)$. Now set $\hat{h}:\wp(X)\longrightarrow\mathbb{B}$ via $\hat{h}(a)=\bigvee\{b\in\mathbb{B}\mid h(b)\leq a\}$. Then this is surjective & monoton. I can prove that it is an hom. exactly in case $\hat{h}=\tilde{h}$, where $\tilde{h}(b)=\bigwedge\{b\in\mathbb{B}\mid h(b)\geq a\}$. Is this the case? Ie does $\forall{a\in A:~}\bigwedge\{b\in\mathbb{B}\mid h(b)\geq a\}=\bigvee\{b\in\mathbb{B}\mid h(b)\leq a\}$ hold?

Comment: oh, just saw your comment. Thanks.

Comment: In the final remarks of your answer, you seem to suggest that $P(X)/I$ can not be an atomless complete Boolean algebra. But this is not true, since for example the instance of $P(\omega_1)$ modulo the non-stationary ideal NS is studied in set theory, and under certain large cardinal assumptions this can be complete (and it is atomless). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @thanks JDH. I’m also interested in an isomorphism in the Category BA, not cBA. So I also don't immediately see why it would be impossible to find an epimorphism between a powerset algebra and a(n atomless) complete Boolean Algebra.

Comment: @JDH I don't know this stuff. I've supplied an argument, please have a look, maybe there's something wrong...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე your argument holds in terms of complete Boolean algebras (cBA). That is, there is no cBA-epimorphism $h:\wp(X)\longrightarrow\mathbb{B}$, if $\mathbb{B}$ is atomless, since then necessarily $h(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in X$ and since $h$ is a cBA-morphism $1=h(X)=\bigvee\{h(x):x\in X\}=0$, which is a contradiction. However this does not exclude morphisms in the category BA, since the last argument cannot be executed for general BA-morphisms. Thus the question remains: is every (complete) BA isomorphic to a quotient of a powerset algebra _within_ the category BA.

Comment: I wasn't objecting to your claims about images of atoms, which are fine. I am objecting to your claims that P(X)/I cannot be atomless and complete, since this isn't true.

Comment: @JDH Oh I see now: if my argument is true then under $\pi:P(X)\to B$ with $B$ atomless, every atom must go to $0$; this just means that the ideal contains all finite sets, and this does not contradict anything... I will withdraw it

Comment: @JDH Ok hopefully this is now correct. Many thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Thomas I doubt these maps coincide in general: there might be $a\in\mathscr P(X)$ such that the only $b$ with $h(b)\subseteq a$ is $0$ and the only $b$ with $a\subseteq h(b)$ is $1$. Dually, there might be subsets of an extremally disconnected space not contained in any proper clopen and not containing any proper clopen, i. e. dense subsets with empty interior. For that to happen, the space must be special - e. g. it must not have any isolated points, but there certainly are such examples.

Comment: @Thomas The paper "[Extremally disconnected spaces,
subspaces and retracts](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81122067.pdf)" by Dow and Vermeer (Top. Appl. **50** (1993), 263-282) contains a characterization of compact subspaces of extremally disconnected spaces, so dually could give a characterization of Boolean algebra quotients of powersets

Comment: That link I supplied in the previous comment seems to be stale. Here is a working one: [Extremally disconnected spaces, subspaces and retracts](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864193900259)